# CAS 6.6.2 Custom Handler return empty

Tags: authentication, upgrade, handler, cas

I've upgraded CAS version from 6.2.5 to 6.6.2. Everything went well and the custom login page shows up. Problem is when I try to login and authenticate, it seems to read my custom handler (customAuthenticationHandler) but it is returning nothing and say I didn't configure well. The log is shown below

`2023-06-12 04:43:02,024 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationManager] (default task-3) Authentication has failed. Credentials may be incorrect or CAS cannot find authentication handler that supports [UsernamePasswordCredential(username=csa1tj, source=null, customFields={})] of type [UsernamePasswordCredential]. Examine the configuration to ensure a method of authentication is defined and analyze CAS logs at DEBUG level to trace the authentication event. 2023-06-12 04:43:02,024 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationManager] (default task-3) [org.apereo.cas.web.customAuthenticationHandler]: []`

Side note : This custom handler is working during CAS 6.2.5, somehow not working in CAS 6.6.2

Already configure custom handler in spring.factories as org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=org.apereo.cas.web.customAuthenticationHandler. I try to print debug log but fail to print them :(